# form submitting

Tags: php

I have a form HTML/PHP, simple, name, subject and comment, which is sent to my yahoo mail, and I have two problems, textarea for comments also sends HTML tags if some one put new line (enter) how to remove that and i got server/host name in subject when receive email, is there way to make some universal subject like name of my site or something like that instead of host name?

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$ToEmail = 'wired@yahoo.com';
$EmailSubject = 'Pitanje sa site.com';
$mailheader = "From :". $_POST["email"]. "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply to :". $_POST["email"]. "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Ova poruka sadrzi pitanje postavljeno na www.site.com \r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Ime : " .$_POST["name"]." \r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email : " .nl2br($_POST["email"])." \r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Naslov : " .$_POST["subject"]." \r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Poruka : " .nl2br($_POST["feedback"])." \r\n";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
echo "Vaša poruka je uspješno poslana! Kliknite <a href=\"index.html\">ovde</a> za početnu stranu ";
};
```

Comment: Can you put your PHP code which is sending the email ?

Comment: I made mistake, it is not subject in yahoo mali problem is from, I got host name in from section in mail.
so I should use:
$headers .= 'From: Me <me@example.com>' . "\r\n"; like Xaltar said...

Answer (score 3):

OK, I didn't really understand your question, but here it goes...

1) Do you want to remove the HTML tags? If so, use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) function

2) You have to send a header. For instance, if you're using `mail()` function, you should have to do something like this:

```
$to = 'destination@example.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$message = 'Your Message';
$headers = 'From: Your Name <email@example.com>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails from you form like this:

```
$to = "email@host.com";
$subject = "Your subject here";
$body = "The comment values here";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

to remove the html new lines you can user the function `str_replace("<br/>","\n", $body);`

or a better way using regex

```
$body = preg_replace("/<br */?>/","\n",$body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "nl2br" for formatting correctly the textarea.

Plus, for the header, you can format them to be like you wish, this should delete the name of the server if you use a header with a "From" :

```
$headers = 'From: Me <me@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

then

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```